# The quotient of totally ordered additive abelian groups which is torsion (value groups in valuation theory)

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field, torsion-groups, ordered-groups

Let $(G,+,\leq)$ be a totally ordered additive abelian group and $(H,+\leq)$ be a subgroup of $(G,+,\leq)$. Let the quotient $\frac{G}{H}$ be torsion and be of finite order $n$ ($|\frac{G}{H}|=n$), where $n$ is a power of a prime number $p\geq 2$ (It is noted that we come across such groups in valuation theory and p-adic number theory as those are the value groups associated to valued fields or local fields).
Now, I have the following question.
How can we write $G$ according to $H$? Is it true to say $G=\frac{1}{n}H$?
In special case, if $H=\mathbb{Z}$, is it true to write $G=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z}$? I saw in Proposition 2.6 of "On saturated distinguished chains over a local field II, J. Number Theory" ( doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2004.12.005 )  that $G=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z}-\frac{p}{n}\mathbb{Z}$! But, I don't know its reason.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Comment: Also, please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am studying a paper in number theory and valuation theory (Proposition 2.6 of "On saturated distinguished chains over a local field II" https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2004.12.005). There the value groups are totally ordered additive abelian groups. The above questions were raised for me there.

Comment: Thank you. Please [edit] the question accordingly. (Not everyone checks the comments.)

Comment: The title of question was changed, however, my problem does not relate to the properties of valuations. I don't understand only the relations about the quotient groups there.